Are there any classes of bipartite graphs that are unique up to isomorphism?
Say I have two parts of a bipartite graph $U$ and $V$ where it is not necessary $|U| = |V|$. Now suppose all the verticies of part $U$ have the same degree $d_1$, and all the vertices of $V$ have the same degree $d_2$.
If this graph exists, is it unique up to isomorphism? Why or why not?

This is similar to counting binary contingency tables, up to isomorphism. The answer is probably no.

It's only unique in trivial cases, $d_1=d_2=0$, or one of $d_1$ and $d_2$ is 1, or the complements of these.

Perhaps the easiest counterexamples are disjoint unions of cycles: $C_4 \cup C_4$ and $C_8$ have the same degrees and part sizes.
